# Unity - confusion over types and instances of components

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference, gameobject

I have a specific question here, but behind it is my confusion about data types and what Unity component names, tags and types really are.

The specific question is this: I want (**at runtime, NOT via the editor**) to be able to create components that can detect collisions and and pass the detection information on to other components. The components are quite simple - (invisible) cubes of various sizes with `Colliders` attached, and `isTrigger` set in each case. Then on collision detection (`OnTriggerEntry()`, `OnTriggerExit()`) to pass collision information on to other components, eg "hi, X has just collided with number 6".

Initially I wanted to be able to hook those calls on the assumption they were events - but it seems they are not events (`MonoBehaviour` overrides, I assume). Reading elsewhere it appears the only way to do this is to attach the script (a C# class, in other words) dynamically after creation of the component.

Since there will be a number of these components, all with the same script (class) attached, I then need to set some internal class variables to tell it what to do / who to contact on collision. That is where the confusion starts.

It seems to me that the Unity designers / documenters, in an attempt not to burden people with too much code, tend to gloss over such details, or at least attempt to explain them in a non-software way. Understandable, but very confusing to someone like me who thinks in terms of software.

The class in the script I attach is going to have a name ('`MyCollisionHandler`', for instance), but that is not an instance of a class, it is just the class definition - or type, if one prefers, eg '`class MyCollisionHandler { ...`'. However, it must be the case (unless it contains only static variables and functions) that once attached to the component, that there is an instance of it.

So, to put it simply - how do I get a reference to the specific instance of the general class type that is attached to that specific collision detecting object? Once I have that I can then use methods to set it up any way I like. If I use `FindObjectOfType<MyCollisionHandler>()`, that isn't going to help because there might be loads of them and it will only return the first found. OK, I can use `FindObjectsOfType<MyCollisionHandler>()` instead and get an array of them - but which is which?

So, it comes back to my general lack of understanding of Unity structure - the difference between component names, tags etc - and how they relate to class definitions and instances. To put it generally - how does one get to individual instances of class objects attached to Game Objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The class in the script I attach is going to have a name
>   ('MyCollisionHandler', for instance), but that is not an instance of a
>   class

It is, and the instance is returned by `GameObject.AddComponent`.

```
MyCollisionHandler handler = gameObject.AddComponent<MyCollisionHandler>();
handler.someValue = 42;
```

Later you can get the instance with `GameObject.GetComponent`, as you would do for any other component.
You would use `FindObjectOfType` and `FindObjectsOfType` if you don't have a reference to the gameobject the script/component is attached to, or you don't care what gameobject has this script/component attached and you just want one/all of them.

Comment: OK, thanks, so the instance of the class type is returned by AddComponent(). So providing I create my object with CreatePrimitive(), hang on to that game object reference, then add the class instance to it with AddComponent() and hang on to that returned reference as well, I should have everything. I notice that all game objects have unique instance ids - it is a pity one cannot search by that, although I suppose one could traverse the tree of game objects at Start() time, and keep a record.

Comment: @nmw01223 You can olso just keep a list of all the game objects that you create with CreatePrimitive() and get the script instance with GetComponent() or keep a list of all the script instances returned from  AddComponent() and get the game object they are attached to from the MonoBehaviours `gameObject` property.